# scroll-function doesn't trigger a result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a style so an element when a special - other - element gets in view via scrolling; as far as I understand it, the command should be like

```
$(".sw_4").scroll(function () {
    $(".sw_1").css({
        "position": "fixed"
    });
    console.log("heyho");
});
```

But it neither logs anything to the console then does something. What do I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your html look like? Do you include jquery? I suggest trying waypoints.

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: use this if you need that functionality more than once.